# .XLSM and set to automatic RUN-TIME

Tags: excel, vba

We are quite new with this Excel VBA (.xlsm). We've managed to create a button and create VBA scripts to manipulate worksheet, etc.

Now my question is - how to set the RUN-TIME mode automatically when this Excel worksheet is open?

I don't see any property in "Application" associated with this.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you saying that the workbook opens in "Design mode" (i.e. when you click on the buttons they are selected for editing rather than clicked upon)?

Comment: If what you are looking is for your code to run when the file is open, then call your procedure from inside this sub : "Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub" inside the "ThisWorkbook" sheetmodule.

Comment: @Chris: Correct and it seems by default is in Design Mode.

Comment: @CaBieberach: In our case, we have 2 buttons and they both needs to be clicked in order to run it. But as I said, the default is Design Mode instead of RUN MODE. Is there any Application class or something that I can set this so utilise Private Sub Workbook_Open() End Sub to set that to RUN MODE?

Answer (score 0):

Try the info in this forum.

http://www.thecodecage.com/forumz/members-excel-vba-programming/159321-macro-exit-design-mode.html

If working with Excel 2007, this code might help:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("DesignMode")
```

-[Source Link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2844231.php)